# We initialize our main object, and it creates a new object in its constructor. When we destroy the main object, what happens to its creation?

Tags: java, object, constructor, creation, destruction

I think the title is very specific, but here's some code to exemplify the question. Also, I realize that aggregation would be the right choice for this particular example, and maybe the question itself poses an OOP smell; however, while I am interested in OOP, I'm more interested in how Java handles object destruction here.

```
public class SuperMarket
{

    private Cashier mCashier;

    public SuperMarket(...)
    {

        this.mCashier = new Cashier(...);

    }

}
```

And running.

```
listSuperMarkets.add(new SuperMarket(...));
```

What happens here, where no other references exist (that may not matter, not sure when writing this):

```
listSuperMarkets.remove(0);
```

Comment: The garbage collector collects those objects eventually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @tkausl mention the garbage collector will delete the object, but to be more specific your object will exist in the heap until the garbage collector delete it.